# Console: Header and Articles in right pane won't go away

Tags: console

I am having trouble understanding all of the different parts of a service console. I've followed the guides online and still have questions. At this stage I've tried to turn everything off, in the app, in the case feed view, case Custom Console Components, and case Layout Properties. None of the changes I make seem to ever take effect whenever I reload. Even if I sign out and sign back in.

One change will show, if I change the fields visible in the case header. None of the other changes, like the header itself, or any of the panes will change.

Am I totally missing something basic?

Comment: To which view are you making these changes.  In Setup? Which one?  CaseCase,  account, opportunity?

Comment: My cases open as a subtab of Contacts. Most of the changes I am making are on the Case Page Layout, specifically a feed view layout, and on the Contacts Page Layout. The other changes were in the App settings, in which I have a console.

Maybe it's something about saving settings across sessions? I saw a selection for that.

Comment: I've noticed that if I close out of all of the tabs in the Console, and reopen a case that I have better success with new changes. Managed to get the side article bar to go away. Although the highlights panel is still inexplicably there.

Comment: check out this to disable highlights panel https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_layoutcustomize_highlights_panel_on.htm&language=en_US